# Get value of span element and output it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, I am more than impressed that you guys took your time to answer this, thank you so much, I did not expect it. Hope well follows you.

To explain my problem, I used that fiddle tool you all had. This is the code I have:

`enter code here`
http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/1/

-What I need, is to sum up the values that get calculated in the spans : budgetI + actualI

Comment: Where's the diff span?

Comment: You should to put quotes around the `id`'s like `<span id="budget"></span>`

Comment: BTW, when/How are you executing this script?

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code to : Use .text() to populate the Span and assign some value to your inputs..(Since you have used jQuery)

http://jsfiddle.net/xubam99v/

HTML Code

```
<pre>
<input id=primaryB type="text" value="100"></input><input id=primaryA type="text" value="100"></input><span id=primary></span><br />
<input id=spouseB type="text" value="100"></input><input id=spouseA type="text" value="100"></input><span id=spouse></span><br />

Budget: <span id=budget></span> <br />
Actual: <span id=actual></span><br />

</pre>
```

Javascript/jQuery Code

```
var primaryBValue = parseFloat($('#primaryB').val()); 
var primaryAValue = parseFloat($('#primaryA').val()); 
$('#primary').html(primaryBValue + primaryAValue);  

var spouseBValue = parseFloat($('#spouseB').val()); 
var spouseAValue = parseFloat($('#spouseA').val()); 
$('#spouse').html(spouseBValue + spouseAValue); 

$('#budget').text(primaryBValue + spouseBValue);
$('#actual').text(primaryAValue + spouseAValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

listen on the change-event to sum numbers after you insert then

http://jsfiddle.net/55c5uqhc/2/

```
$('#primaryB,#primaryA,#spouseB,#spouseA').change(calc);

function calc() {       
                var primaryBValue = parseFloat($('#primaryB').val()); 
                var primaryAValue = parseFloat($('#primaryA').val()); 
                $('#primary').html(primaryBValue + primaryAValue);  

                var spouseBValue = parseFloat($('#spouseB').val()); 
                var spouseAValue = parseFloat($('#spouseA').val()); 
                $('#spouse').html(spouseBValue + spouseAValue); 

                $('#budget').html(primaryBValue + spouseBValue);
                $('#actual').html(primaryAValue + spouseAValue) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a trigger upon which you populate the `<span>`s, also use `text()` instead oh `html()`
Here's example(probably a bad one but it's good place to start):

function:

```
$('input').keyup(function(e){
    var spouseBValue = parseFloat($('#spouseB').val()); 
    var spouseAValue = parseFloat($('#spouseA').val()); 
    var primaryBValue = parseFloat($('#primaryB').val()); 
    var primaryAValue = parseFloat($('#primaryA').val());
    $('#spouse').text(spouseBValue - (-spouseAValue)); 
    $('#primary').text(primaryBValue - (-primaryAValue));
    $('#budget').text(primaryBValue - (-spouseBValue));
    $('#actual').text(primaryAValue - (-spouseAValue));
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/epv27bqp/4/)

Comment: Thank you so much, @Hardik,  but I think that is not what I intended - here is a fiddle to clear out things:http://jsfiddle.net/5xzSy/1/

-What I need, is to sum up the values that get calculated in the spans : budgetI + actualI